# gnuplot: How to store two date values from inside file in variable

Tags: file, variables, gnuplot

Out of a power measurement device I get a csv file like this:

```
Position Date Time P(SUM) Unit
```

and the values look like this:

```
0 10/17/2015 18:10:11 0.214 kW
0 10/17/2015 18:10:13 0.211 kW
0 10/17/2015 18:10:15 0.413 kW
0 10/17/2015 18:10:17 0.522 kW
```

Now I want to use the first date and time in the file and the last one to be stored in a variable each so I can use it in the title.
So I have two questions:
How do I store a date value from a file in a variable?
How can I access the first and last one?

I use gnuplot 5.0 on windows.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this old workaround, system independent; get the idea and modify if needed:

```
f(x,y)= ( y==0 ) ? ( first = x ) : (last= x)
plot "data.dat" us ($1):(f($4,$0))
```

The first line defines a function with an `if` on the second parameter ( test `?` action_if_true `:` action_if_false ).  It should be a value... but we perform an assignment.

With the second command you *plot* the file through that function... passing as second parameter the column 0 (the row number, that starts from 0). So with the first row of the file you store the current value in the variable `first`, and for all the other rows you will update the value of `last`.

Now you can try

```
print first , last 
0.214 0.522
```

After you will be free to do your real graphic, to use the variables as you wnat; moreover you can use other tricks to avoid to see the fake plot and so on...

How to put in a single variable that format of date/time is another question... and yes, you can nest the `if` and eventually select the line you want.

Comment: Why the down-vote?!? Without any comment the down-vote is useless. Feel you free to give an answer if you think this is wrong, but it works...